# The same Android service instance for two apps

Tags: android, service

I have two Android apps that uses exactly the same library. This library defines one Android service.
Firstly, I bind the service in the first app - it's ok.
Secondly, I bind the service in the second app and in the result second service's instance is raised and after it two services are running (one for first app and one for second app).

I'd like to have only one instance of service, ie. when first app bind service - the service starts working. Now, when second app bind service I'd like to use this one that is running and have only one service instance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done with three modules:

1. A library module that uses AIDL to define the interface of the service that will be bound to.
2. An app module that has the library module as a dependency and which defines a service conforming to the interface specified in #1. This app hosts the service that will be bound to.
3. Another app module that also has the library module as a dependency but which **does not** define the service implementation.

Both apps (#2 and #3) can bind to the service. The difference is #2 binds to it locally while #3 binds to it remote via IPC (inter-process communication). Note that in order for the app which binds remotely (#3) to work, the other app which actually implements that service (#2) must be installed first.

[This page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) discusses how to use AIDL.

**EDIT**

What you are suggesting is to package the Service in both APKs. This should result in each app binding to its local Service, which is not what you want.

The only thing I can think of to make this work would be for your Service to have `android:enabled="false"` in your AndroidManifest. When you try to bind to the Service, if binding fails (`bindService()` returns false), then you can use [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to enable your local Service and try to bind again.

In theory the first app will have nothing to bind to, so it will enable its own service, but subsequent apps will find and bind to the first one. You'll have to try this out and make sure it works for different installation orders, as well as testing what happens if you have two apps installed and you uninstall the one whose Service is the "Active" one.

You will still need AIDL in order to define the binding interfaces and allow binding across processes.

With all that said, I wonder if the effort is even worth it.

Comment: I meant something different. I've two apps that uses exactly the same library, but I want to have apps transparent for themselves. I don't want to know or investigate that another app is installed or not.
The best solution for me is following - if one app binds service then second app binds exactly the same instance that is running. However if service is not running, its instance is created.
Then, the solution will be also working for more apps using this library. Furthermore, I wouldn't know the name of one app in the second app and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare like this for the service`<service name='you service name' android:process='your_service_full_name(including package name)'`, do not use `:`.